# Missing stack trace in Xcode debugger when exception is thrown on both iOS simulator and device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, build

When my app throws an exception it prints the following in the debugger output:

```
First throw call stack:
(0x310f88bf 0x3829d1e5 0x31e76015 0x31e7640d 0x31e764c5 0x9e903 0x9edfb 0x32b15d55 0x32b20e8d 0x310cb2dd 0x3104e4dd 0x3104e3a5 0x33c7cfed 0x330c0743 0x3267 0x3220)
```

Software stack:
Xcode 4.2 in Lion 10.7.2 (Xcode 4.1 is not installed)

I am leaning towards this this being an Xcode bug, but do you see anything obvious that I missed?

### What I have tried / checked

Build Settings:
Debug
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy = NO
Strip Linked Product = NO
Optimization Level = -O0 and-Os
Symbols Hidden By Default = YES and NO
Compiler = LLVM 3.0 and LLVM GCC 4.2

Scheme:
Debugger = GDB and LLDB

Cleaning:
Clean
Clean Build Folder
Delete Derived Data Directory  (remove from organizer)

Devices:
iOS 5 Simulator
iOS 5 iPhone 4
iOS 5 iPhone 3Gs

Random:
I originally had this problem with both Xcode 4.1 and 4.2 installed, so uninstalled both and reinstalled just 4.2

Tried with different projects with the same results.

When fiddling with breakpoints I see this in the debugger output before the exception:

```
Catchpoint 36 (throw)Catchpoint 37 (catch)Pending breakpoint 2 - "__cxa_begin_catch" resolved
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.

Catchpoint 36 (exception thrown).warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found the issue: Well not me but Joe (a [phillyCocoa](http://phillycocoa.org) member)… But since he is not on SO, I will post his solution.

The deployment target was set to 4.0, but since the 4.0 debug symbols must be downloaded separately in Xcode 4.2, the DSYM wasn't valid.

2 ways to fix:
1. Install the debug symbols for 4.0 from the Xcode preferences.
2. Set the deployment target to 4.3 or higher.

Comment: In Xcode 4.x, how did you download the debug symbols? There is no such option in Preferences->Downloads.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that sticks out is that development builds should probably have optimisation switched off altogether with `-O0`.